# How to upload an image after changing the default bucket

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, angularfire2

I was trying to change the default bucket to firestorage, i've looked it up on the internet and I found on the firebase page the following code:

```
bucket2 = firebase.app().storage(bucket);
```

However, before, i was using:

```
this.afStorage.upload(remakeNewPath, file);
```

to make the upload. Now, if I do this:

```
this.bucket2.upload(remakeNewPath, file);
```

It does not work anymore, it seems that the value of bucket2 doesn't have the property upload like this.afStorage did. How would I go about uploading it now that i'm using a diferent way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is not function called upload in this appraoch.

You need to use the following code to upload the image to the new path:

```
 firebase.storage().ref().child(remakeNewPath).put(file);
```

here remakeNewPath is the path and you need to define the storage bucket in your configuration used for firebase.

Comment: that does solve the uploading problem, but now I cant use this.bucket2.ref().getMetaData() Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [documentation for AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md), it looks like you can set a custom bucket with:

```
import {AngularFireStorageModule, BUCKET } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: BUCKET, useValue: 'my-bucket-name' }
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I cant really do that, because that's already done to use default bucket and if I do this it will change all the instances for the default bucket that is being used else where. I have to change the bucket only in one specific service, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`BUCKET` injection token to customize the storage bucket](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#import-the-ngmodule) and afterwards use one of the [following methods to upload blobs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#import-the-ngmodule): `put()`, `putString()`, `upload()`.

Comment: I cant really do that, because that's already done to use default bucket and if I do this it will change all the instances for the default bucket that is being used else where. I have to change the bucket only in one specific service, but thank you